# Quais as principais diferenças entre Angular, React e Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, angular, react, vue.js, front-end

Em um projeto **SPA** que em breve será usado também em um *app mobile*, preciso saber quais as principais diferenças para me decidir em qual *framework* devo me especializar.

Comment: recomendo a leitura: https://medium.com/by-vinicius-reis/o-que-e-react-ng2-auleria-vue-e34b0c77b5a1

Comment: Faltou o Node.js kk

Answer (score 24, accepted):

| Tópico | Angular | Vue.js | React |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Rank de popularidade](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017#technology-frameworks-libraries-and-other-technologies) | 2 | N/A | 4 |
| [Apreciação](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted-frameworks-libraries-and-other-technologies) | 6 | N/A | 1 |
| Quantidade de posts (SO) | [226.473](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) | [5.288](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue.js) | [37.731](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) |
| Modelo operacional | MVC | View | View |
| Categoria | Framework<sup>1</sup> | Library | Library |

<sup>1</sup> Um framework é mais completo do que uma biblioteca, cobrindo mais aspectos de uma aplicação padrão - como controle de rotas, recursos, *caching* e CORS, por exemplo.

---

<sup>Nota: Dados de 2017.</sup>

Answer (score 7):

[AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) (versão 1) já é obsoleto. É um framework que incluí roteamento, validação de formulários, etc. Usa modelo MVC (Model-View-Controller). Seu sucessor é Angular, que já está na versão 4 (não teve versão 3) e aplicativos são escritos em TypeScript. Angular é diferente do original AngularJS 1.X. Angular foi criado pelo pessoal da Google.

[React](https://facebook.github.io/react/) é uma library (biblioteca) que foca no desenvolvimento de UI com componentes reutilizáveis. É como se fosse um melhoramento do jQuery. React é normalmente usado em conjunto com outras bibliotecas como o Redux, React Router, etc, assim formando um aplicativo de frontend completo. React foi criado pelo pessoal do Facebook.

[Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/), como o React, é uma biblioteca focada na View do aplicativo. Foi criado por [Evan You](https://github.com/yyx990803), desenvolvedor da Google que trabalhou no desenvolvimento do AngularJS. Por isso, Vue.js tem forte influência dos aspectos do AngularJS.

Acho que cada um têm seu forte e recomendo dar uma olhada na estrutura e código de cada um. Pessoalmente gosto do React. Era grande fã do AngularJS, mas me converti. Nunca usei Vue.js, mas parece ter uma certa popularidade recentemente.

Conclusão:

AngularJS: framework, com tudo já incluído, mas agora versão 1 é obsoleta. Aprenda TypeScript para desenvolver para Angular (v2+).

React: library, aplicativos rápidos devido ao Virtual DOM. Encoraja o uso de vanilla JavaScript e ES6.

Vue.js: parece haver os aspectos do Angular, mas numa biblioteca em vez de framework completo.

Answer (score 4):

Vue.JS e React.JS são voltados para a View segundo os sites de cada um.
Angular.JS se diz mais robusto.

Apesar de ser possível algumas coisas que o Angular JS faz com Vue e React, Angular JS acaba tornando-se mais robusto.